# How to return column letters instead of column numbers with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working on Chapter 12 of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python and it is about working with spreadsheets using `openpyxl`. I have an object called '`c`' that is '`B1`' of the spreadsheet. Whenever I use '`c.column`' it returns the number '`2`' instead of the letter '`B`'. The example on the page returns the letter so I'm wondering why mine is different.

Comment: Have you passed the wb into a new variable? `sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')` `sheet['A1'].column`  returns A for me.

Comment: I did. It looks like openpyxl has a function that can change what is returned, I'm figuring out how to call the function now.

Comment: The book is out of date, use `cell.column_letter` instead, though you should rarely need to do this.

Comment: That is handy, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Openpyxl has utilities to solve this problem, so here is the solution.

`from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter`

then `c.column` can be passed in the function `get_column_letter(c.column)` which will return the letter instead of the number.